# Instantiating derived class Object in Base-Class main-Method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have got the following problem (I simplified it).

I programmed an abstract class, like this:

```
public abstract class Calculation{
    abstract public int multiply(int x);
    public final static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            // I want to call the Method multiply here. 
            // Therefore I need an object here!
        }
    }
}
```

My abstract class has a main-Method which should evaulate my args and then call the method multiply. Now I want to make some other classes like

```
public class MOne extends Calculation{
    public int multiply(int x){
        return x;
    }
}
public class MTwo extends Calculation{
    public int multiply(int x){
        return 2*x;
    }

}
public class MThree extends Calculation{
    public int multiply(int x){
        return 3*x;
    }

}
```

If I call on the console:

```
java MOne 5
java MTwo 5
java MThree 5
```

I want java to print 5,10 and 15.

Sadly I don't know how to instanciate the MOne-class respectivly MTwo and MThree in the Calculation-class. Does anyone know, how to make it?

Comment: have you tried: MOne one = new MOne(); and so forth?

Comment: And how could this help? I want any class, which inherits from Calculation instantiate. I am developing a framework and I don't know, how the multiply Method will look like, the user has to take care, as well as the user has to choose the class name. The only thing I know is, he will inherit from Calculation.

Comment: your (abstract) base class isn't supposed to know about inheriting classes. You could, I guess, on loading your classes load all the beans and check if they pass an instanceof test. But if the classes are in another library, good luck with that one

Comment: Could you elaborate on this "framework"? How is it supposed to be used? Because this could be as simple as just having the user provide the `Calculation` implementation to as complex as run-time discovery of implementations with instantiation via reflection (one might consider making use of the [service loader mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to be "between" those two extremes).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but expensive because you have to search all classes on the classpath to find those that extend Calculation. A good tool for this is [ClassGraph](https://www.baeldung.com/classgraph).

Try this code:

```
List<Class<Calculation>> calculations;
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph().enableClassInfo().scan()) {
    calculations = scanResult
        .getSubclasses(Calculation.class.getName())
        .loadClasses(Calculation.class);
}
for(Class<Calculation> calculation : calculations) {
    Calculation calculationInstance = calculation.newInstance(); // needs null constructor
    System.out.println("Java " + calculation.getName() + " " + calculationInstance.multiply(5));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not, what I am looking for. I don't want to loop any class that extend Calculation. If someone calls MOne.main("5") I want the result to be 5. If someone calls MTwo.main("5") I want the result to be 10 and so on. So the static main Method needs to know, what class was used to call the main method.

Comment: Understood - I have posted another answer

Comment: @MichèleS. Note that static methods are not inherited. If someone calls `MTwo.main(new String[]{"5"})` then it will call the `main` method in `Calculation`, unless you define another `main` method (with the same signature) in the subclass so that it **hides** (not overrides) the one in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You may need to find the equivalent to `sun.java.command` for non-Oracle JVM.

```
public abstract class Calculation {
    abstract public int multiply(int x);

    public final static void main(String[] args)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,
            InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    String className = System.getProperty("sun.java.command").split(" ")[0]; // Oracle JVM only
    Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName(className);
    Method multiplyMethod = loadedClass.getMethod("multiply", int.class);
    Object newInstance = loadedClass.newInstance();

    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

        System.out.println("java " + "className " +multiplyMethod.invoke(newInstance, x));
         
    }  
}
```

Run it with the name of the inheriting class as the first argument and inheriting and base class on classpath:

```
java -cp path/to/jar;path/to/mine_class MOne 5
```